# How to add a Google static IP address to Linux and make it work with docker

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, static-ip-address, netplan

I've purchased a static IP address from Google Cloud. The problem is, I don't know how to properly add it to netplan. I've tried multiple different things, but none seem to work. Well, I am able to connect to the server and do stuff, but Docker does not seem to recognize it, which is a huge problem for me. This is how the netplan from Google Cloud looks normally:

[View the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKSHo.png)

I've tried following azure guides, so I've added 60-static.yml with [the following content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROgUr.png).

Of course, I've applied it with netstat apply. It is also important to note that during my testing, the whole Cloud Firewall was disabled, so it could not make any problems.

When I, for instance, try `docker run busybox nslookup google.com`, I get the [following output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9jTw.png). It is the same for every single website.

Hope someone comes with a solution! Thanks !

Comment: Please include the text you are asking about **in your question**. Don't post images of text, and don't post **links** to images of text. This makes your question harder to read and less accessible.

Comment: What do you mean by add it to net plan? On which service do you want to use your static IP?

Comment: Does `nslookup google.com` work on the Docker host? What it the output?

Comment: Nope, https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9jTw.png

Comment: I meant, can the GCE VM instance where Docker is running, resolve "google.com"? What is output of the command `nslookup google.com` (without `docker run`) in the command prompt of the VM instance? Is External IP actually bound to the VM instance? You can check with this command: `gcloud compute instances describe my-vm --zone=my-zone --format=yaml | grep "\(External \| natIP\)"`.